# Python question about randomizing from standard input

Tags: python

1. My problem is that in my `r.py` file which takes two command line arguments (random num. generator seed and num. of random moves to make), I'm trying to read from a standard input file and print a output board in an 3x3 output format that is like the standard input file except randomized. The standard input file contains only a value in a 3x3 format like

```
123 
456 
789
```

with a new line after every 3 numbers just like a matrix.

2. I used `sys.stdin` to read my input file, but how do I use it correctly so I can randomize the values of the input file (3x3 format with new line after every 3 numbers: 123 456 789) to reach my desired output file which should be randomized but in 3x3 format like the input file.
3. Here is what I have so far. I can get it to print the original input file, but I can't get it to be randomized when I print it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sys, random
dinput=sys.stdin.read()

if (len(sys.argv) != 3):
    print()
    print("Usage: %s [seed] [number of random moves]" %(sys.argv[0]))
    print()
    sys.exit(1)

def main():
    random.seed(int(sys.argv[1]))
    number_of_moves = int(sys.argv[2])

    for x in range(number_of_moves):
        move = random.randrange(8) 
        print(move)
        print(dinput)      

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the input to a list, use `random.shuffle()` to shuffle it, then convert it to a 3x3 grid of nested lists. You can use `input()` to read a line at a time from standard input.

```
nums = []
for _ in range(3):
    line = input() # read a line
    for c in line: # turn each character into a list element
        nums.append(c)

random.shuffle(nums)
board = [nums[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(nums), 3)] # convert the flat list to a 3x3 grid
```